# Typedef a container of function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

Simple question; right now I have something like this:

```
typedef void(*MyFunctionPointer)(int);
typedef std::vector < MyFunctionPointer > MyFunctionPointerContainer;
```

However, I want to typedef this container in one row, skipping the first typedef, how can I do this?

Comment: Question - what for? Is this for an obfuscation contest?

Comment: Do you want to save one code line? Two typedefs look much better.

Comment: EboMike: I simply wanted to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
typedef std::vector < void(*)(int) > MyFunctionPointerContainer;
```

Comment: Damn you! Beat me by 4 seconds; +1 and nuking my duplicate.

Comment: +1, but I would still go with the typedef because I'd much rather write `for( MyFunctionPointerContainer::iterator it = ... )` than `for( std::vector < void(*)(int) >::iterator it = ...)`

Comment: `typedef MyFunctionPointerContainer::iterator MyFunctionPointerIterator; `  would also work...

Comment: With the new C++0x auto keyword, this will be a moot point and was defined for these types of convoluted type typing.